# SQL query that outputs items that do and do not share the same attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql

So say I have five fruits, one is the focus and four others are of interest for long term farming. These fruits of course have many attributes, some shared share and other attributes are unique to each fruit.

The following SQL query and variations of it get the job done for determining which attributes are shared. I was able to get what I was looking for from the answer promptly provided [here][1] but still digging to get the report I need.

```
SELECT ATTRIBUTE, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ATTRIBUTE, FRUIT 
    FROM FRUIT_TABLE
    WHERE ATTRIBUTE IN (
        SELECT ATTRIBUTE
        FROM FRUIT_TABLE
        GROUP BY ATTRIBUTE
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FRUIT_NAME) > 1 )
        ORDER BY ATTRIBUTE, FRUIT_NAME ) AS RESULTS 
 GROUP BY ATTRIBUTE
```

However I am having trouble figuring out how I would be able to also determine attributes that are not shared by Apple (for example).

The ideal output I am looking for would look like this:

```
Fruit | Shared w/ Apple | Not Shared w/ Apple
---------------------------------------------
Orange       1                       5
Banana       0                       8
Pear         6                       2
Plum         2                       9
```

Thanks in advance for any help that is sent this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a self join of the `FRUIT_TABLE`:

```
SELECT ft1.FRUIT_NAME AS Fruit,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ft2.ATTRIBUTE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As 'Shared with Apple',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ft2.ATTRIBUTE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As 'Not Shared with Apple'
FROM FRUIT_TABLE ft1 LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ATTRIBUTE, FRUIT_NAME
    FROM FRUIT_TABLE ft
    WHERE ft.FRUIT_NAME = "Apple"
) ft2
ON ft1.ATTRIBUTE = ft2.ATTRIBUTE
GROUP BY ft1.FRUIT_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks Tim..this is working although its not outputting the fruit at all. Ideally fruit is in the first column. I tried adding of course but wasn't able to get it to work. Figure you may be able to help faster than I can hack at it :)

Comment: After thinking about this maybe its easier to just query a list of attributes that are not shared with Apple?